# Android VItamino Media player class not found exception

Tags: android, media-player, vitamio

I'm using vitamino libraby to play videos.when i run it,showing 'class not found' error

Oncreate

```
if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_player);
    videoView.setVideoPath("https://www........com/........");
```

XML

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vitamio_player"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

manifest
[image]
Logcat
[image]

Gradle

[image]

Comment: How did you add this library??
Could you share your gradle?

Comment: i have added jar file into lib folder and imported.edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Make this with Gradle.
In your build.gradle add these lines.

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2' }
```